# how can i trigger a rake task on every 4th sunday of every month in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schedule, rake-task, whenever

i am having a rake task. i want that task to be scheduled to run on every 4th Sunday of every month. i am using whenever gem. how can i define logic in `config/schedule.rb` so that it will run on every 4th Sunday of every month in Rails? please help me.

this is my rake task `app/lib/tasks/my_task.rake`.

```
task :do_something => :environment do

end
```

this is my code in `config/schedule.rb`

```
every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do 
  runner "Employee.make_checkin_out"
end
```

how can i change the above logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger a rake task using whenever in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785557/how-to-trigger-a-rake-task-using-whenever-in-rails)

Comment: but  there is no answer for this question.

Comment: Yes there is, i wrote one last week.

Comment: Not only is this question a duplicate, but the author's the same!  @John - if you didn't get an answer for your other question (which you did, actually) then please don't just slightly change the wording and put it up as a different question:  this just wastes people's time.

Answer (score 1):

[whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gives a facility to generate a cron job. This is a scheduler for rake tasks. You can define like

```
every 1.month, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_morning_every_month"
end
```

If you want something like 1st sunday every month use cron editor like

`0   12  1-7 *   *   [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Sun" ]`